# SQL Query Select OR using another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I make this work ?

```
strQuery = "
SELECT UNIT_NO,DRIVER1,DRIVER2,PHONENUMBER,PHONENUMBER_2,PHONE1,PHONENUM2
from UNITS
where PHONENUMBER=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  "OR " & PHONENUMBER_2=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  "OR " & PHONE1=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  "OR " & PHONENUM2=" & objRS("PHONE")"
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Eihter we have wrong coloring on SO or there is something wrong with the query. Nice to see it colorful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strQuery = "
SELECT UNIT_NO,DRIVER1,DRIVER2,PHONENUMBER,PHONENUMBER_2,PHONE1,PHONENUM2
from UNITS
where PHONENUMBER=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  " OR PHONENUMBER_2=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  " OR PHONE1=" & objRS("PHONE") &
  " OR PHONENUM2=" & objRS("PHONE")
```

Comment: still getting Unterminated string constant :-(

Comment: I suppose the phone number columns are strings, as such, you should use single-quotes around the data.  There's also a trailing quote at the end of the last line that should be removed.

Comment: @G Mastros - you're probably right; I've posted this to check the syntax coloring because there were additional `&`s (and missing spaces before `OR`s) and in the editor window coloring takes a lot of time and in that moment I've seen the question is closed so I let it be. It's accepted though but I would say it will be deleted after some time. Thanks for the hints

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding your values with ' characters.

Comment: tried it... keeps saying Expected end of statement at the first one

Comment: Show us what strQuery is after the query is built. It should look something like "SELECT UNIT_NO, DRIVER1, DRIVER2, PHONENUMBER, PHONENUMBER_2, PHONE1, PHONENUM2 from UNITS where PHONENUMBER = '123-456-7890' OR PHONENUMBER_2 = '222-333-4444'".